# Node.js CORs Request

Tags: node.js

I am currently attempting to use the questions API here...
https://opentdb.com/api_config.php
to set up a game to test out what I have learned in javascript. When I was using jquery in the browser, it was no problem and worked great. Now I am attempting to recreate the quiz with react/redux using a node.js server on localhost:3000.

Now when I make the request I get a CORS error. All of the answers on here seem to be turning off the CORs request on the server (which I have no control of).

Is there a way to work around this or am I basically stuck if I want to make this request using a browser?

Here is my current code, though I've tried it with the basic fetch command

```
export default function fetchQuestions(numQuestions = 5, category = 10,    difficulty = 'any') {
  const url = createURL(numQuestions, category, difficulty)
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, (error, response, body) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log(body)
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: CORS permission issues from a browser can ONLY be fixed on the server.  There is no CORS when one server is requesting to another so you could have your client ask your node server to make the request from the 3rd party server and then return the result back to the client.  This is called "proxying".

Comment: it's not clear to me where your code is running.  does that code sample get run by node or does it get run in a browser?

Comment: The code sample is run in node. I could run it in the browser but I am trying to understand the redux-react flow. It seems that putting this code on the browser side isn't how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Jfriend - is proxying in this situation common? I did come across that earlier but I thought it was a hack and not the proper way to do things.

Comment: If you want access to something in the client that you cannot get direct access to from there (for CORS reasons or other reasons), it's perfectly acceptable to ask your server to do some work for you.  Yes, it's a work-around, but it's how you solve those types of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to npm install the packages used below with:
npm install cors
npm install express

In a new file in the node folder write the code below:

```
var express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
var app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: ' https://opentdb.com/api_config.php',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
  }

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    // res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // app.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');
    // app.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // app.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    // app.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
///products/:id
  app.get('/helloworld', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'});
  })

  app.listen(3000, function() {
      console.log("CORS-enabled web server listening on port 3000");
  });

var response_text;

var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//Get the html of the website
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
        xhr.send();    
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

      // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
      // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
      xhr = new XDomainRequest();
      xhr.open(method, url);
      xhr.send();
    } else {

      // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
      xhr = null;

    }
    return xhr;
  }

  var url = "https://opentdb.com/api_config.php";

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    throw new Error('CORS not supported');
  }

  xhr.onload = function() {
    response_text = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(response_text);
    console.log(values);
    // process the response.
   }

   xhr.onerror = function() {
     console.log('There was an error!');
   }
```

Then cd to the file directory in the terminal and write:
$ node filename.js

It will then be listening on http://localhost:3000/helloworld
Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Is old question but maybe someone else still has this issue using opentdb API.

For me it worked when i remove the options for json.

Before i had:

```
await fetch(
          'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean',
          {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          }
        )
```

And it failed with the same CORS error had the OP.

Without specify the Content-Type, it works:

```
await fetch(
          'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=hard&type=boolean',
          {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'GET'
          }
        )
```

Hope it helps someone!